# Open an embedded PDF link after click of an anchor tag

Tags: laravel, pdf, cross-browser, embed

Am working on a Laravel project whereby am fetching some response from an API and storing in a variable. Basically the response is pdf document code which when clicked will open as a PDF document on the browser,,

After fetching it am storing in a variable and then passing to the view. On the view I Have created an **anchor tag which when clicked the embedded document should open** but it aint working as expected

**Controller Hitting the API and getting the response**

```
public function createQuote(){
    $dat = [
        'sts_quote_number' => $quoteRef
    ];

    //STS PDF Quote
    $quotePdf= $this->global_Curl_Meta(
        $dat, 'api/v1/travel/sts-quote-doc')->data;

    //dd($quotePdf);

    $quote_data = view("B2C::travel.quote", compact('quotePdf'))->render();
}
```

**Response after dd($quotePdf)**

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJaqrrK0KNCAwIG9iago8PAovQ3JlYXRvciAoQXBhY2hlIEZPUCBWZXJzaW9uIFNWTiB0YWdzL2ZvcC0xXzEpCi9Qcm9kdWNlciAoQXBhY2hlIEZPUCBWZXJzaW9uIFNWTiB0YWdzL2ZvcC0xXzEpCi9DcmVhdGlvbkRhdGUgKEQ6MjAxODEyMjcxMTQwMDYrMDInMDAnKQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNSAwIG9iago8PAogIC9OIDMKICAvTGVuZ3RoIDExIDAgUgogIC9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlCj4+CnN0cmVhbQp4nJ2Wd1RU1xaHz713eqHNMNIZeu9tAOldQHoVhWFmgKEMMMwAIjZEVCCiiIhgAwkKGDAaisSKKBaCggL2gAQBJQaj2FDJjKyV+PLy3svL7497v7XP3ueeXc5aFwCSdyorLQuWAiCNJ+AHe7nSI6Oi6dh+AAM8wAAzAJisrAz/EM9QIJKPhxs9S+QE/kWvhwEkft8yEu8F/j9JszL4AgCgQBFbsDlZLBEXijg1R5Ahts+KmBqfImYYJWa+6IAilhNz4iIbfvZZZGcxs9N4bBGLz5zBTmOLuUfEW7OFHBEjfiIuyuZyckR8W8SaqcI0rojfimPTOExRDiiS2C7gsJJEbCpiEj802E3ESwHAkRK/4PgvWMDJFYiTckvPWM3nJiYJ6LosPbqZrS2D7s3JSeUIBEaBTFYKk8+mu6WnZTB5qwFYzPmzZMS1pYuKbG1ma21tZG5s9kWh/uvi35S4t4v0MuhzzyBa3x+2v/.....
```

**Anchor tag on the viw which when clicked the div containing embedded PDF should open**

```
<td colspan="2">
      <i class="fas fa-print quote"></i> 
      <!--Anchor tag to click-->
      <a href="#d">Print Quote</a>

      <!--The div to open-->
      <div id="d"><embed src="{{ $quotePdf }}" height="750px" width="750px"></div>
</td>
```